COUNT(DISTINCT ...) OVER (PARTITION BY ...) in Postgrsql
I have the following query:
SELECT s.first_field,
       s.second_field,
       t.third_field,
       s.fourth_field,
       ROUND(
               (SUM(mt.volume) * 100.0 /
                 SUM(mt.volume) / COUNT(DISTINCT mt.question_id) OVER (PARTITION BY s.first_field, s.second_field, s.fourth_field)),
               2
       ) AS score,
       fsd.volume
FROM my_table mt
         LEFT JOIN second s
                   ON mt.second_id = s._id
         LEFT JOIN third t
                   ON mt.third_id = t._id
WHERE s.fourth_field IS NOT NULL
  AND s.fifth_field IS NOT NULL
  AND s.fifth_field = 'Test'
GROUP BY s.first_field, s.second_field, t.third_field, s.fourth_field, mt.volume
;

But I'm getting the following error: [0A000] ERROR: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions
I don't know what to try as I don't use SQL too much

can you prepare an intermediate relation using a CTE that already solves the distinct problem, and then join on it and apply a window function on one of its fields?

SUM(mt.volume) * 100.0 / SUM(mt.volume)=100.0  May be, you want first sum(mt.volume) calculate over(...)?

As the error message points out distinct isn't supported when using a window function. So I suggest you need an intermediate subquery to aggregate the value you hoped to achieve using the window function but as there is no sample data provided I cannot be certain the following is exactly what you need, but something like the following should help:
SELECT
      s.first_field
    , s.second_field
    , t.third_field
    , s.fourth_field
    , ROUND((
            SUM(mt.volume) * 100.0 / SUM(mt.volume) / SUM(count_q)
            ), 2) AS score
    , fsd.volume
FROM second s 
INNER JOIN (
            select
                  second_id
                , sum(volume) as volume
                , count(DISTINCT question_id) count_q
            from my_table
            group by
                  second_id
            ) mt ON s._id = mt.second_id
LEFT JOIN third t ON mt.third_id = t._id
WHERE s.fourth_field IS NOT NULL
    AND s.fifth_field IS NOT NULL
    AND s.fifth_field = 'Test'
GROUP BY
      s.first_field
    , s.second_field
    , t.third_field
    , s.fourth_field
    , mt.volume
;

Note I have also changed the order of tables as it appears that your existing where clause conditions on table s forms an inner join equivalent - so there is no benefit from the left join.
